# Retrieve saved data from a text file but only show a portion of the data Java JGrasp

Tags: java, jgrasp

I have programmed a game were I have made it so that you can save your score, if you have a good score you will be in the top 10. My problem is when I retrieve the data with the saved names, I only want a proportion of that data to be shown, in this case 10 names.

Here is my code.

```
public static void Highscore(List<Highscore> data) {

   String HighscoreList = "";

      try {
          //Textfilens name
          String filname = "Highscore.txt";
          Scanner inFil = new Scanner(new File(filname));

             while(inFil.hasNext()) {

             String name = inFil.next();
             String percent = inFil.next();

             HighscoreLista += name + "\n" + percent + "%" + "\n\n";

          }  inFil.close(); 
      }   catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File was not found!");
         }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, HighscoreList);

}//Highscore ends
```

How do I only show a proportion of the players in the final message (Highscorelist).

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Create a counter variable in the function to track the number of items in the while loop and check the counter variable along with the while condition

```
 public static void Highscore(List<Highscore> data) {

 String HighscoreList = "";
  int counter =0;

  try {
      //Textfilens name
      String filname = "Highscore.txt";
      Scanner inFil = new Scanner(new File(filname));

         while(inFil.hasNext() && counter<=10) {
          counter++;

         String name = inFil.next();
         String percent = inFil.next();

         HighscoreLista += name + "\n" + percent + "%" + "\n\n";

      }  inFil.close(); 
  }   catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File was not found!");
     }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, HighscoreList);

}//Highscore ends
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, however, I just wonder what is "inFil.hasNext()" in the while loop?